# iwlwifi Microcode SW error detected, restarting 0x0 when on 5GHz

Tags: linux, network-interface, firmware, iwlwifi

Whenever I have the card connected with 5GHz, I experience sudden and seemingly random drops in connectivity that can last a little while.

When I use 2.4GHz (11n_disable=1), these errors don't occur. I've tried to find solutions online, but none of these have worked. I would rather not use 2.4GHz, as the speeds are quite slow for downloading games or large software packages.

I'm using Arch Linux, kernel 6.1.11-x64v1-xanmod1, although this error has occurred on Zen and mainline kernels as well.

Dmesg/Journal logs below:

````
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.ea3728ee.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A6F6 | trm_hw_status0
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0048961A | branchlink2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0047905E | interruptlink1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006CB4 | interruptlink2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3C6 | data1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001000 | data2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA0C046FA | beacon time
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x40ECEC76 | tsf low
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000032B | tsf hi
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBFA5566E | time gp2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEA3728EE | uCode version minor
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89002 | board version
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0B02001C | hcmd
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA6F22002 | isr0
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00004000 | isr1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08101802 | isr2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x40400084 | isr3
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x005B019C | last cmd Id
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B3C6 | wait_event
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00004288 | l2p_control
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00003422 | l2p_duration
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000E7 | l2p_addr_match
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x15120642 | timestamp
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C0B8 | flow_handler
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20100705 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088A3A | umac branchlink2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084CC4 | umac interruptlink1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00004424 | umac data1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEA3728EE | umac minor
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBFA55653 | frame pointer
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886C60 | stack pointer
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x005D010C | last host cmd
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM data1
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5E14C0E | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFE31D892 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAFF1EAF2 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9F2EACB5 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2C659D7A | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB2BB68F4 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Feb 14 23:28:55 beren kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR```
````